# MS Access SQL - Aggregate Count with 2 Example Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I have a situation where I need to query from a 2 table in MS Access.
I'm new to this SQL access.

```
Table: UserInfo
===================
| UserID | Gender | 
===================
|  K01   |   M    |
|  K02   |   M    |
|  K03   |   F    |
|  K04   |   M    |
===================

Table: OrderInfo
===================================
| OrderID  |  Type    | UserID_FK |
===================================
|   1      |  Food    |    K01    |
|   2      |  Food    |    K01    |
|   3      |  Toolkit |    K02    |
|   4      |  Food    |    K04    |
|   5      |  Toolkit |    K03    |
===================================
```

The question is:
I want to query so the result produce this table, how can I do it in MS Access?
I'm thinking that I should do a subquery but I don't know how to do it.

```
Table: Summary
================================================================
| UserID | Gender |  CountOfToolkit | CountOfFood | TotalCount |
================================================================
|  K01   |   M    |       0         |      2      |     2      |
|  K02   |   M    |       1         |      0      |     1      |
|  K03   |   F    |       1         |      0      |     1      |
|  K04   |   M    |       0         |      1      |     1      |
================================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

First, Type is a reserved word in MS Access.
You should avoid using reserved words.
Having said that, try this:

```
SELECT   a.UserID, a.Gender, SUM(IIF(b.[Type] ='Food',1,0))  AS CountOfFood, SUM(IIF(b.[Type] ='Toolkit',1,0)) AS CountOfToolkit, COUNT(*) AS  TotalCount
FROM     UserInfo a INNER JOIN OrderInfo b ON a.UserId = b.UserID_FK
GROUP BY a.UserID, a.Gender
```

Answer (score 1):

This crosstab query doesn't rely on having just Food & Toolkit as your types - it will count any new types you add.

The `NZ` wrapped around the `Count(sType)` ensures the 0 values are shown, while the `CLNG` ensures it's still treated as a number rather than text.
You could just use `Count(sType) AS CountOfType`.

```
TRANSFORM   CLNG(NZ(Count(sType),0)) AS CountOfType
SELECT      UserID
            ,Gender
            ,COUNT(sType) AS TotalCount
FROM        UserInfo LEFT JOIN OrderInfo ON UserInfo.UserID = OrderInfo.UserID_FK
GROUP BY    UserID, Gender
PIVOT       sType
```

Comment: May I ask. Is there's any query that possible to imitate `this` like in javascript?

Because I'm want to do subquery that refer to the main query primary_key, is that 'this' kind of syntax exist?

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea.  I've never used javascript.